# MySQL set column value to upper case value of another column

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement where in my sql a column 2 would always have the uppercase value that is column 1,

Not sure ow to do this in mysql. I want to do something like this , I know the syntax below is incorrect but writing some psuedo code as to make it clear what I am trying to achieve

```
create table sakila.testupper(name varchar(50),
uppername varchar(50) not null default as select upper(@name));
```

Comment: Oh, you want the default value for the second column to be the uppercase value from another column.

Comment: easy enough with a view, might be enough depending on your use case

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could accomplish this across most version of MySQL with a trigger on insert or update: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you're after looks like this: "create table sakila.testupper (name varchar(50), uppername varchar(50) generated always as (upper(name)));". However, you'd need a recent release of MySQL version 5.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the table do this automatically but you can create a trigger for all future `INSERT`s.  With a trigger you will need to maintain a separate table.

```
drop table if exists p;
drop table if exists q;

create table q (name nvarchar(59),uppername nvarchar(59));
create table p (name nvarchar(59));

create trigger trig_thing after insert on p
for each row
begin
insert into q set name = new.name, uppername = upper(new.name);
end;

insert into p (name) values ('Some nice gentleman');

insert into p (name) values ('A sweet old lady');

select * from q;
```

Your original table will keep only the name, but each insert will cause a trigger to insert the same data into your new table with name and uppername.

If you already have names stored in a table you should insert into your second table to get them in line before you set up the trigger:

```
insert into q name, upper(name) from p;
```

[here is](http://rextester.com/SLNH51984) a functional example